# AD Security Group not resolving in People Picker

Tags: 2010, active-directory, central-administration, groups

I created a new global AD Security Group and tried to add it to my Farm Admins group in Central Admin. It worked no problem. When I try to add it to a site in any other group outside of Central Admin, the people picker cannot find the new group. I can find other existing groups, but when I make a new one, even if its properties match the existing ones, it cannot be found.

What gives?

Comment: Are you creating that group in the same OU as other groups that are present?  Do you have any exclusion filters configured on the User Profile Sync?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem when I was accessing a site using a non fully qualified domain name. I.e. The site had been setup with

> name.domain.com

. Whenever I accessed the site using

> name

the site would function correctly apart from the people picker. If this is the case make sure you have an alternate access mapping in place for both scenarios.